# What happens to beta sites that don't achieve certain goals?

Tags: support, beta

Our [proposal page](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6591/travel) lists some goals. I think we will have some trouble with the question quantity and visits-per-day measures (maybe I am a pessimist, but for now I don't see any huge progress in these areas).

So I want to know: what will happen to our site? Some proposals are closed and some are in indefinite beta—what is this based on?

Comment: also see http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/does-this-site-have-a-chance-of-succeeding/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best place to check to see how a site is doing is [the site directory](http://stackexchange.com/sites?sort=newest&expand=true). Here are the stats from Travel compared to other sites that started around the same time (within four weeks):

```
Site           Days old  Questions  Answers   As%     Users   Visits/day   New 200+   Qs/day  New Meta posts

Productivity   14         91         299      97%     396     165          37          6.4       62
Travel         15        212         403      93%     356     190          50         15.0      136
Gardening      28        337         635      97%     411     195          66          5.9       29
Philosophy     29        177         460      93%     429     153          44          2.2       28
Astronomy      35        201         468     100%     437     140          24          3.2       19
Japanese       36        421        1.1k     100%     462     291          37          6.8       83
German         43        399        1.2k      99%     574     176          29          5.1       24
```

While there's always room for improvement, I don't think Travel has anything to worry about.

Answer (score 5):

After two weeks in beta, I think the number are pretty good. Maybe I'm wrong, but anyway it's too soon to judge them. We should keep promoting the website and the number of visitors will go up

Answer (score 5):

The answer is, that if a site meets those goals after 90 days in beta it goes live. And if not, it stays in beta. Look at skeptics, for example, which has been in beta 129 days. It could happen that a site would eventually close, but it would take a long time.

All our numbers are good except number of users and number of visits. Keep asking and answering questions, and publicize the site however you can. (Use the personalized links on every question and answer and you might earn some badges, too.)

Comment: I'm a bit worried that we're having trouble with the non-subjective/one right answer/no open questions SE rules for newcomers not used to StackExchange, such as may come from Google searches: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/781/beach-holidays-in-indonesia

Comment: Agreed. Traffic from search engines that arrives en masse before there are enough users with close votes and edit power likely to be around and able to react is a problem. That's why traffic should grow slowly. If we had ten times our current traffic, the moderators could not keep up.

Comment: I think we need to try to figure out best ways to let people know that otherwise good travel questions are no necessarily good travel.SE questions. If they get downvotes or close votes and no gentle feedback/explanation why would they even consider staying?

Answer (score 4):

There are sites like [Writers.SE (public beta for 228 days)](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1623/writers) and [Audio Recording and Production (public beta for 209 days)](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4/audio-recording-and-production) with much 'worse' statistics on some counts than Travel.SE. So I wouldn't be worrying less than two weeks into the beta for this site.

Area 51 also indicates that "Eventually, 90% of a site's traffic should come from search engines." I don't know the split between [referrals sent by Google](http://site%3atravel.stackexchange.com) vs referrals by other search engines, but [a look at Bing's results currently shows they have indexed less than 10 pages of this site](http://www.bing.com/search?q=site%3atravel.stackexchange.com&go=&form=QBLH&filt=all); [Blekko has none](http://blekko.com/ws/?q=travel%20stack%20exchange); [DuckDuckGo shows two](http://duckduckgo.com/?q=site%3atravel.stackexchange.com). (This is without even starting to consider local search engines that are strong in their own markets.) Traffic, hopefully, will grow once we've been around for a while and indexed by more search engines.